# Project architecture or setup for .Net Core Web API project

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Can anyone help me to suggest a good architecture or Project setup for .net Core Web API Project?

How to handle dependency injection?
How to handle routing?
How to handle authentication?
How to do CRUD operations with the MS SQL server?
What are the best practices that should follow?

Sample project in git most preferred.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really too general to answer in a prescriptive way, but Microsoft recommends using the Razor Pages approach for new ASP.NET Core web apps. This tutorial gives you a Razor quick-start, and touches on many of the concepts you asked about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

.NET Core also has a standardized dependency injection model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

As for authn/authz, there are some decisions for you to make about whether you trust other identity providers or manage users yourself, but this will give you a start. The related sections will get you the rest of the way toward almost any auth approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1